# Softmax Jacobian in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Suppose I have a simple one-layer neural network:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_dim])
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, output_dim]))
a = tf.matmul(x, W)
y = tf.nn.softmax(a)
```

Thus, the variable `y` is of dimension `batch_size` by `output_dim`. I want to compute the Jacobian of `y` with respect to `a` for each sample in the batch, which will be of dimension `batch_size` by `output_dim` by `output_dim`. Now, mathematically, the Jacobian (dy/da)_{i,j} = -y_i y_j for i != j and otherwise, (dy/da)_{i,i} = y_i (1 - y_i).

I was wondering how to compute this Jacobian of the softmax with respect to its input in TensorFlow? I know that `tf.gradients` will compute the gradient of a scalar with respect to a tensor, so I figure some combination of looping in TensorFlow with either `tf.gradients` or even just trying to implement the analytic form given above should work. But I am not sure how to do this in TensorFlow with its ops and would appreciate any code to do this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `tf.gradients` applies a sum over the `output_dim`. Solution: unstack then restack. Not sure how this affect efficiency...

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 3
input_dim = 10
output_dim = 20

W_vals = np.random.rand(input_dim, output_dim).astype(np.float32)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_dim])
    # Use a constant for easier checking
    W = tf.constant(W_vals, dtype=tf.float32)
    a = tf.matmul(x, W)
    y = a
    # remove softmax for easier checking
    # y = tf.nn.softmax(a)

    grads = tf.stack([tf.gradients(yi, x)[0] for yi in tf.unstack(y, axis=1)],
                     axis=2)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    x_vals = np.random.rand(batch_size, input_dim).astype(np.float32)
    g_vals = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: x_vals})

# check gradients match
tol = 1e-10
for i in range(batch_size):
    if np.max(np.abs(g_vals[i] - W_vals)) >= tol:
        raise Exception('')
print('Gradients seem to match!')
```